# divergent or convergent as limits go to infinity?

Tags: calculus

My question concerns generalized integrals.

I can understand that $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^2} \,dx$ is divergent and thus $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^2} \,dx$ is  divergent by definition (since an integral is convergent only if it is convergent on all its intervals). I can also understand that $\int_{-A}^A \frac{x}{1+x^2} \,dx \xrightarrow {} 0$ when $A \xrightarrow {}\infty$ since it is an odd function and corresponding values "cancel out".

What I can't wrap my head around is how it is possible for the 2 to be true at the same time. That is how $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^2} \,dx$ can be divergent and $\int_{-A}^A \frac{x}{1+x^2} \,dx$ can be convergent when A is close to $\infty$. I guess the answer lies in the limits, but I still find it hard to grasp.
Could you help me?

Comment: The [WIkipedia article on Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Examples) (almost) has your integral as an example.

Comment: The reason lies in the definition of the convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx$: both integrals  $\int_{-\infty}^af(x)\,\mathrm dx$ and  $\int_{a}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ have to be convergent (supposing f(x) defined  on $\mathbf R$).

Comment: I'll never understand why people hate definitions so much. Ok, you have to learn them, but hey, that's not their fault. And there is a definition of improper integrals, and it's not secret.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think of divergence when a principal value exists is that we can make the integral equal to every real value we could want, thus the assignment of any particular value would be absurd. Take for example the limit

$$\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{-A}^{2A}\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx = \lim_{A\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+4A^2}{1+A^2}\right) = \log 2$$

In fact we can get any real number we want with the appropriate bounds

$$\lim_{A\to\infty}\int_{-A}^{e^tA}\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx = t$$

as a continuous version of the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).